# Insert data in a partition of CouchDB from java

Tags: java, couchdb, cloudant

I'm using cloudant API for CouchDB in JAVA. I've created a partitioned database from Java but now i don't know how to create a partition and insert my json in this one.

```
final String dbName = "cinema";
        CloudantClient client = ClientBuilder.url(new URL(url)).username(username).password(passw).build();
        System.out.println("Server version: " + client.serverVersion());
        Database db = CreatePartitioned.createPartitionedIfNotExists(client, dbName);
        db.createIndex("movies"); //doesn't work
```

I have this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.cloudant.client.org.lightcouch.CouchDbException: 400 Bad Request at http://127.0.0.1:5984/movielens/_index. Error: bad_request. Reason: invalid UTF-8 JSON.
    at com.cloudant.client.org.lightcouch.CouchDbClient.execute(CouchDbClient.java:597)
    at com.cloudant.client.org.lightcouch.CouchDbClient.executeToInputStream(CouchDbClient.java:648)
    at com.cloudant.client.api.Database.createIndex(Database.java:391)
    at provaCouch.Prova_CouchDB.main(Prova_CouchDB.java:20)
```

I have to create 3 partition and on the net there are poor information. Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? What errors do you see?

Comment: @xpqz you're right, I'm sorry. I edited the question just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not sending the correct argument to `createIndex()`.

See the [docstring](https://github.com/cloudant/java-cloudant/blob/master/cloudant-client/src/main/java/com/cloudant/client/api/Database.java#L379) for the createIndex method, and the API [doc](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/Cloudant/api?topic=cloudant-query#creating-an-index) it references. You will probably want to use the index builder instead (com.cloudant.client.api.query.JsonIndex.Builder).